# DefaultFolder to the media-field-component in the plugin config

Tags: shopware6

How can I provide a default folder for the media-field-component fields in the Shopware plugin configuration?

The documentation of the component suggests that there is a property called "defaultFolder". Can I set this in the plugin config?
https://component-library.shopware.com/components/sw-media-field

According to Shopware and the quality guidelines, the graphic must be loaded into a media folder. However, I cannot find an example of how to do this or whether it is possible at all.

Shopware relies on the following section in the Code Guidelines:
https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/guidelines/testing/store/quality-guidelines-plugins#own-media-folder

I have already tried the following, but it is not working.

```
<component name="sw-media-field">
    <name>image</name>
    <label>Image</label>
    <defaultFolder>example</defaultFolder>
</component>
```

I was expecting the media-file to be uploaded to the folder with the name example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `defaultFolder` property takes the name of an entity associated to the default folder.

For instance there's a `media_folder` entity with the name "Product Media". This entity has an association to another entity `media_default_folder` which in turn has a field `entity` with the value `product`. This is to denote that this folder should primarily contain media elements that belong to `product` entities. If you wanted your `sw-media-field` instance to assign media to that folder, you will have to refer to the entity instead:

```xml
<component name="sw-media-field">
    <defaultFolder>product</defaultFolder>
</component>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It works as described. Do you happen to have a code example of how to create a folder in the install method? Or an example. Unfortunately, I can't find anything in the documentation on this.